# Use dispatch_time with a float value

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point, delay, grand-central-dispatch

I have a simple iOS app which needs to delay a certain block of code before it can be run.

I am using dispatch_time method to achieve this and it works very nicely. Just one question though, dispatch_time takes in an integer, so the time that you can set are only allowed to be whole numbers such as 1.0 seconds or 3.0 seconds, etc....

I want to set it to delay by 0.5 seconds. How can I do this? Below is my code:

```
    int64_t time_delay = 1.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, time_delay * NSEC_PER_SEC);

    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        /*
           my block of code....
        */
    });
```

Comment: The fact that the code that you copied assigns a floating-point constant to an integer should be a hint. Change time_delay to double. dispatch_time takes integers, but as nanoseconds. So you can't get 1000000000.5 nanoseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `int64_t` but a `CGFloat`. It will work fine.

```
CGFloat time_delay = 0.5f;
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much indeed :) I will accept this once SO allows me to tick it :)

Comment: Note that CGFloat is 32 bit on 32 bit machines. To get full precision on every device and avoid subtle differences between 32 and 64 bit, use double.

Comment: @gnasher729 I'm only storing values between 0 and 1.0 in intervals of 0.1 each time, so I don't need a double...? So I am only storing values like 0.1, 0.2, 0.7, etc...

Answer (score 1):

dispatch_time() takes nanoseconds as second parameter. Remove NSEC_PER_SEC from second parameter and your delay will be in nanoseconds

Comment: thanks! i don't understand why i got a down vote for it

Answer (score 0):

```
    double delay = 2.25;

    // 2250000000 = 2.25 * 1000000000
    dispatch_time_t offset_time = delay * NSEC_PER_SEC;

    // current mach_absolute_time + offset
    dispatch_time_t fire_time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, offset_time);

    // dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2.25), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    dispatch_after(fire_time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"time %llu", t);
    });
```